# Different ways of determining $\mathbb E(X^n)$

Tags: random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,2a]$ with $ a > 0 $.
The task was to determine $\mathbb E (X^2)$.

My approach: $F_{X^2}(x) = \mathbb P(X^2 \le x)$ = $\mathbb P(- \sqrt x \le X \le \sqrt x)$. Thus we got:

$$\boldsymbol{F_{X^2}}(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0 \\ \sqrt x \over 2a, & 0 < x < 4a^2 \\ 1,  & x \ge 4a^2 \end{cases}$$

Note that $$f_{X^2}(t) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}({\sqrt x \over 2a}) \boldsymbol{1}_{0 < x < 4a^2} = {1 \over 4a \sqrt x} \boldsymbol{1}_{0 < x < 4a^2} $$
 Finally we got:

$\mathbb E (X^2) = \int_{0}^{4a^2} {x \over 4a \sqrt x} dx = {4a^2 \over 3}$.

In the solution however, it simply says:

$\mathbb E (X^2) = {1 \over 2a} \int_{0}^{2a} x^2 dx = {4a^2 \over 3}$.

My question: Let $X$ be some real-valued random variable with pdf $f(x)$. Does for all $X^n, n \in \mathbb N$ w.l.o.g follow that $\mathbb E(X^n) = \int_{\mathbb R} x^n f(x) dx$? Why?

Comment: Yes, indeed for any reasonable function $E(\phi(X))=\int \phi(x)f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: What do you mean by reasonable?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Addition to Dave's answer: Let $\phi$ be the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of $U(0,2a)$, then we have
$\phi(t)=\frac{e^{2ita}-1}{2ita}$, $\phi''(0)=-\frac{4a^2}{3}$ and finally 
$$E(X^2)=\frac{\phi''(0)}{i^2}=\frac{4a^2}{3}$$

Comment: @Fakemistake I haven't seen this method before, but it's a cool addition I think.

Comment: @Pazu I'm sure you will learn it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value for a continuous random variable $X$ with pdf $f(x)$ is $E(X)=\int_{\Bbb R}xf(x)dx$. We also have that $E(g(X))=\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)f(x)dx$ for a function $g$ of the random variable. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for more information.

So in your case, $g(x)=x^n$, so we have $$E(X^n)=\int_{\Bbb R}x^nf(x)dx$$

---

Another way to tackle this problem is using the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) or mgf. This allows you to compute any moment of $X$ by differentiating the mgf and evaluating at $t=0$. For a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ the mgf is given as
$$m(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}\qquad\text{if $t\neq 0$}\\1\qquad\qquad\text{if $t=0$}\end{cases}$$
and then $E(X^n)=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}m(t)\vert_{t=0}$

Comment: Does this hold for any measurable function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Pazu In fact, $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ can be any function. The above result will hold provided $$\int_{\Bbb R}|g(x)|f(x)dx<\infty$$

Comment: i.e. $|g(x)|f(x)$ must not be unbounded (on a non Null set).

Comment: The integral must converge to a real number.